# Pagination with function based view with dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to paginate the pages with the help of Paginator. Have written this so far but I don't understand what would I pass in the context. Simply doing this doesn't work, I think my knowledge with Paginator is limited.

```
customerproducts = customerproductsjsondata.json()
customerproducts_list = customerproducts['data']
paginated_products = Paginator(customerproducts_list, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to return multiple things, like queryset for the current page, current page number, whether there is prev or next page, number of total records, number of total pages based on the offset.

You need to get the page from Paginator depending on the page number:

```
page_number = request.data.get('page_num')

page = paginated_products.page(page_number)

total_records = paginated_products.count

total_pages = paginated_products.num_pages

queryset = page.object_list

has_prev = page.has_previous()

has_next = page.has_next()
```

but you can User DRF's included pagination support by following the link https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/